# CouchDB won't work over SSL

Tags: ssl, openssl, couchdb

I am running the [CouchDB Docker container](https://hub.docker.com/_/couchdb/), V.2.1.1. Everything is working at this point except for SSL. I am following the [CouchDB documentation on SSL setup](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/latest/config/http.html#secure-socket-level-options). The container has OpenSSL 1.0.1t.

As shown in the documentation, I am using a self-signed certificate. When I try to connect to the SSL page on port 6984:

Chrome tells me

```
"ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED".
```

curl gives me

**curl -k https://localhost:6984**

```
curl: (35) LibreSSL SSL_connect: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL in connection to localhost:6984
```

In the server log, I get a whole lot of this.

```
hello terminated with reason: no function clause matching ssl_cipher:hash_algorithm
```

A search on this last error turns up information indicating that the Erlang version has an issue. However, I believe the CouchDB container has an already patched version. I did try and upgrade with:

```
apt-get install Erlang
```

This made no difference. Search results also point to the version of OpenSSL having a problem. I upgraded to OpenSSL 1.1.1 from source, Recreated the certificates, and still, the issue persists.

As requested, here is the output from a few more commands.

**openssl s_client -connect localhost:6984**

```
CONNECTED(00000005)
140736008328136:error:140790E5:SSL routines:SSL23_WRITE:ssl handshake failure:/BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/libressl/libressl-22.50.2/libressl/ssl/s23_lib.c:124:
---
no peer certificate available
---
No client certificate CA names sent
---
SSL handshake has read 0 bytes and written 318 bytes
---
New, (NONE), Cipher is (NONE)
Secure Renegotiation IS NOT supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
No ALPN negotiated
---
```

**curl --version**

```
curl 7.54.0 (x86_64-apple-darwin17.0) libcurl/7.54.0 LibreSSL/2.0.20 zlib/1.2.11 nghttp2/1.24.0
Protocols: dict file ftp ftps gopher http https imap imaps ldap ldaps pop3 pop3s rtsp smb smbs smtp smtps telnet tftp
Features: AsynchDNS IPv6 Largefile GSS-API Kerberos SPNEGO NTLM NTLM_WB SSL libz HTTP2 UnixSockets HTTPS-proxy
```

**curl -k -v https://localhost:6984**

```
* Rebuilt URL to: https://localhost:6984/
*   Trying ::1...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to localhost (::1) port 6984 (#0)
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* Cipher selection: ALL:!EXPORT:!EXPORT40:!EXPORT56:!aNULL:!LOW:!RC4:@STRENGTH
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: /etc/ssl/cert.pem
  CApath: none
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* LibreSSL SSL_connect: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL in connection to localhost:6984
* stopped the pause stream!
* Closing connection 0
curl: (35) LibreSSL SSL_connect: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL in connection to localhost:6984
```

**curl -k --ciphers DEFAULT https://localhost:6984**

```
curl: (35) LibreSSL SSL_connect: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL in connection to localhost:6984
```

**curl -k --ciphers ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384 https://localhost:6984**

```
curl: (35) LibreSSL SSL_connect: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL in connection to localhost:6984
```

The output from the following three commands is very similar. I will just show the differences. However, it seems that a handshake is now taking place with all of these commands.

**$ openssl s_client -tls1 -connect localhost:6984**

```
CONNECTED(00000005)
SSL handshake has read 1762 bytes and written 400 bytes
New, TLSv1/SSLv3, Cipher is DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1
    Cipher    : DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA
    Session-ID: 18C5DF9DCA1B8AA0DBD33258BCD253053F8D1D91B524B0561A1C0FAB8CFB5146
    Master-Key: FD0C57E4E8FB992C0323D43930C104D82B69C4200F42E03EDB51E38A47448D62FDCB6E813583E2177A339B74B4D0CC4A
    Start Time: 1525593658
    Timeout   : 7200 (sec)
```

**$ path/to/brew/version/of/openssl s_client -connect localhost:6984**

```
CONNECTED(00000003)
Peer signing digest: SHA512
Server Temp Key: DH, 1024 bits
SSL handshake has read 1796 bytes and written 537 bytes
New, TLSv1/SSLv3, Cipher is DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1.2
    Cipher    : DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256
    Session-ID: A19D67CBE634843181859DB2C3C4D1A3416C9F7DAA85CF470D412FE723AD49B4
    Master-Key: 61B711B9BEDB651868607527439D01B421780C7D584FCE68C4754A7A7F3563923409C03F4B68BB7914397B48A92FC756
    Key-Arg   : None
    PSK identity: None
    PSK identity hint: None
    SRP username: None
    Start Time: 1525593604
    Timeout   : 300 (sec)
```

**$ path/to/brew/version/of/openssl s_client -tls1 -connect localhost:6984**

```
SSL handshake has read 1762 bytes and written 397 bytes
New, TLSv1/SSLv3, Cipher is DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1
    Cipher    : DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA
    Session-ID: 6CC7FFE1C7CE258F105C7ADD5D8A9C0DFFB26A5A9555EB218EE48E519D361208
    Master-Key: 2D6DFAC01544F6FF5F4138D877A4105485D5A2F77B58B4796822625E2E602455C38E3EEB2CBACE07FA03D207B07C715E
    Start Time: 1525593717
    Timeout   : 7200 (sec)
```

**$ curl -k --tlsv1 https://localhost:6984**

```
curl: (35) LibreSSL SSL_connect: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL in connection to localhost:6984
```

**$ curl -k --tlsv1.0 https://localhost:6984**

```
{"couchdb":"Welcome","version":"2.1.1","features":["scheduler"],"vendor":{"name":"The Apache Software Foundation"}}
```

So I am guessing there is a problem with the built-in version of LibreSSL? The next question is what can be done about it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to dig deeper, can you post the output of the following commands?

```
$ openssl s_client -connect localhost:6984

$ curl --version

$ curl -k -v https://localhost:6984

$ curl -k --ciphers DEFAULT https://localhost:6984

$ curl -k --ciphers ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384 https://localhost:6984
```

---

By the way, I notice that your `curl` is using [LibreSSL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LibreSSL) **not** OpenSSL as indicated in the error message you're getting:

> curl: (35) **LibreSSL** SSL_connect: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL in connection to
>   localhost:6984

---

When you try openssl:

```
$ openssl s_client -connect localhost:6984
```

You are getting this error:

> CONNECTED(00000005) 140736008328136:error:140790E5:SSL
>   routines:SSL23_WRITE:ssl handshake
>   failure:/BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/libressl/libressl-22.50.2/libressl/ssl/s23_lib.c:124:

Can you please report the output of this command:

```
$ openssl s_client -tls1 -connect localhost:6984
```

Also, it might be inferred that the cause of the problem is your macOS default version of LibreSSL/OpenSSL. To fix the problem, try to install the `brew` version OpenSSL and run this command again, and please report the output:

```
$ path/to/brew/version/of/openssl s_client -connect localhost:6984
```

Also please post the output of this too:

```
$ path/to/brew/version/of/openssl s_client -tls1 -connect localhost:6984
```

---

Based on your reported outputs, please try the following command and see if it works:

```
$ curl -k --tlsv1 https://localhost:6984
```

Comment: I am using curl on my mac. OpenSSL is what I used in the docker container to create the certificate. The Docker container is running on the same machine and I have opened the ports on the container. So when I am calling curl localhost this is on my Mac OS but it should be forwarded to the docker container right? When I do the same without SSL it works.

Comment: I have posted the output you requested. It seems the installation of LibreSSL may be the issue. I'm not sure how to fix this as it is provided by Apple and there seems no way to replace it.

Comment: @user1757006 Please see my updated answer and report the output.

Comment: how did you fix this @user1757006 ?

Answer (score 0):

If your SSL certificate is self-signed:

---

You didn't show your `curl` command, but I guess you are **not** using the `-k` option, but you should:

```
-k, --insecure
              (TLS) By default, every SSL connection curl makes is verified to be secure. This option allows curl to proceed and operate even  for
              server connections otherwise considered insecure.
```

Comment: I am using a self-signed certificate. Using the -k option gives the same error.

Comment: I did not get this resolved on my mac but I'm only testing on my laptop so I don't care. When I move to production I will of course not be using a self-signed certificate.

Answer (score 0):

I can't say for sure that this is the actual answer to the particular problem the OP had some three years ago and counting, but here's AN answer — at least to what MY problem was when debugging that same error.

In my case, I was moving from macOS to Linux Mint, and by extension, from MacPorts and Homebrew to apt and less user-centric ways of handling software.

I say less user-centric, because the root of the problem stems from here. In particular, I had rsynced all my development and configuration files from my macOS system to this new Mint system, and being that the approach on my Mac was to run nginx, php-fpm, couchdb, etc. as me — that is to say, as `daniel:staff`, then my SSL certificates, found in `~/Projects/SSL` were also owned by me.

And, because best practice is to lock down your certificates with a `0600` umask, and some applications refuse to run if they're not, my certificates were not readable by anyone but me, including the  `couchdb` user which couchdb runs as by default on "properly configured" systems like Linux.

`SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL` does hint at this — at least, it hints to the error relating to a system call, as opposed to something with the certificate structure itself.

Also, we see `No client certificate CA names sent`, `read 0 bytes`,  `New, (NONE), Cipher is (NONE)` and several more `NONE`s, all hinting to nothing actually being read.

Again, it MAY be that the OP's problem was different, but in my case, a simple `chmod` on the SSL files to allow couchdb to actually read them and not throw up here.

I'm continuing on to generate a new self-signed certificate and give it to couchdb explicitly, but anyway, this was the problem behind these errors on my particular box.